# grab query params from redirect angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, auth0, auth0-lock

My problem is I'm using auth0 as my authentication service, now when a user logs in and is authenticated it gets redirected back to my callback url which then decides where to send the user now my problem is when you get redirected back to your callback url from auth0 there are queryParams in the url string like so..

`http://localhost:4200/account/login/callback#access_token="dsadsadsadsa dasdsaa"` just as an example but then in a split second the query string is removed and its left at `http://localhost:4200` now Im trying to grab the query Params using this method

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params);
});
```

now this should work but the console.log is an empty object every time, I think its because of that url change that happens..

Is there some way I can grab the query params before that removal??

**EDIT**

Basically what is happening is I'm getting authenticated then I get redirected to

`localhost:4200/account/login/callback?acessToken="dasdasdaefssves"`

but then the route changes to

`localhost:4200/account/login/callback`

without the query parameters before the `activatedRoute` function gets a chance to run!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: i think you have to check in `NavigationStart and NavigationEnd` where your router is being captured simultaneously

Comment: @Sanoj_V not sure what you mean?

Comment: can you tell me what type of path you have set in your router.

Comment: Its all done via auth0 so you set a redirectUrl, which is `http://localhost:4200/account/login/callback`

Comment: have you tried same path different parameter url like this: `/account/login/callback` and `/account/login/callback/:acessToken `

Comment: @Sanoj_V Ive just tried that but Im getting redirected back to my base route now instead

Comment: could you paste your angular routes?

Comment: Hey I am facing this issue too........ need to extract code from redirected url which is again redirected by angular routing in split seconds

Answer (score 0):

Notice your redirect-url is `http://localhost:4200/account/login/callback?access_token="dsadsadsadsa dasdsaa"`

but angular routes it to `localhost:4200/account/callback`

**NOTE**

You don't have that **/account/login/callback** route defined in angular. But you have **/account/callback** route instead. Angular tries to resolve the route and redirects its to **/account/callback** without the queryParams.

Define the route in angular and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: I declared the route like this /login/callback/:authInfo but now I keep getting redirected to base url? any ideas?

Comment: Please see updated question I had a typo in there, i actually meant to write /account/login/callback the whole time so this isnt the issue

Comment: If your auth service is redirecting to `http://localhost:4200/account/login/callback?access_token="dsadsadsadsa dasdsaa"` then you need to define a route in your angular project for `account/login/callback` because `?access_token="dsadsadsadsa dasdsaa"` is a querystring.

Comment: yeah I understand that but I do actually have that route defined I just didnt type it properly in my question which has now been fixed

Comment: in the comment you wrote you declared a route `/login/callback/:authInfo`. I believe it should be `login/callback` instead.

Comment: No so I originally had it as login/callback but then after your comment I changed it to /login/callback/:authInfo and neither worked

Comment: any idea on how to preserve querystring

Answer (score -1):

I didn't get your complete question but as much as I understand. You want to get query parameter from URL.

To get query parameter from URL You need to do this.

```
 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}
```

This is how you can get all the query params from URL.

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
                .map((params: Params) => params.params)
                .subscribe( (params) => {
                     if(params && params['access_token']){
                        console.log(params['access_token']);
                     }
                 });
```

Comment: Sorry no this isnt the question, basically what happens is the query parameters are on the url for 1s before they are removed so when this.activatedRoute runs there are no query parameters to grab which is why I keep getting back an empty object